# How to align contents in different columns vertically for Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The codes can be found at:

http://www.bootply.com/Z85ieOd2nu

I tried to create a row contains `<h2>` inlines with `<button>`. However, I found they are aligned weirdly in the result..

Does anyone have ideas about this?  (How to align all of them in center vertically?)

Comment: try #center h2{margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `line-height:70px;` in CSS. assign the height of the `.row` (which in your case it is "70px") to button's CSS and you're done.

http://www.bootply.com/FyZOo7ach4

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. However, when I changed the font size of `<h2>`, it still looks not perfect.. http://www.bootply.com/C3sdH3WSMq#

Comment: you need to either give it a fixed height, and equal the `line-height` to that or calculate the height based on the font size of `h2`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap gives top and bottom margins to h tags. 
Here also  has top and bottom margins but  does not have any margin ( that's why it is stuck to the top ).

To resolve this, either remove the margins from  tag or provide top and bottom margin to the  tag as(in this case):

```
button {
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```